Is it OK to use the same field in the database to store both a percentage rate and a fixed money fee?
I am trying to convince a colleague that their proposed approach to storing a "fee" is problematic.
The "fee" can be either

a percentage rate, e.g. 50%, which is stored in the database as 0.5 (float) or
a fixed money amount, e.g. $100, which is stored in the database as 100.00 (float).

I already know that storing money as a float is fatal. I do not want to discuss this.
The proposed approach is to store both the percentage rate and the fixed money amount in the same field. Then there is another filed called fee_type with enum value PERCENT or FIXED which tells us how to interpret the float.
I think this is problematic and creates undue complexity.
I would rather put the % and fixed fees in separate fields.
Can I please get some validation or contradiction on this? Am I crazy for thinking that it is wrong to use a single database field to store what is sometimes a % and sometimes a money?
My main 3 reasons are:

more future-proof (if we ever fix the horrible money-as-float problem, these fields will have to be split anyway)
safer (avoids problem of fee being 20000%, for example, which the data could technically allow)
simpler UI implementation (this is a little bit subjective but I can not imagine a UI where it is not simpler to have the % and the fixed fee in separate fields).

UPDATE: I know it is also wrong to store the % fee as a float. I wish now that I had lied and said they are both stored as decimals, to avoid that discussion here. :)

Both approaches technically work, and I'd try to argue based on the queries you'd perform on these fields. I cannot imagine a scenario where putting different kinds of data into the same column will simplify any queries. What a single column gives you is a guarantee that there is only one fee per item, but you can also model that via a check constraint. In some situations where fees are more complicated, a JSON column could be interesting. Regarding the issue of floats, note that SQL DBs will support a Decimal type

Neither solution is ideal because SQL does not have any built-in support for tagged unions, but I would also prefer to have separate fields for percentage and amount, since they are really different data types, and you avoid the risk of treating one as the other. (You can add a constraint to ensure they are not both non-null) UI considerations should not be a part of it though - the UI layer should be able to present it as you want regardless of the schema.

@JacquesB They could both be null. They could both be non-null. The fee_type field I proposed would tell us which field to use. Having both non-null makes sense in the case of a HTML form where the user can toggle to select which fee type they want. In this situation, we would "remember" their choice for each type.

What's missing in this question is what your colleague thought you were going to get from doing this.  Be sure to ask that before dumping all over the idea.

I've read this three times and I don't see how 20000% is being avoided.

Just a side note, storing percentages as floats is also potentially problematic.

the problem is that your use case is so simple that any approach works. try adding in more concerns, like currency, changes in the fee over time, more complex calculations x% but not less than £Y etc. only then will you have concrete arguments for the more principled approach

Another concern is the units associated with each field type.  One is a unitless percent.  The other is dollars.

Also, don't forget the potential use-case where one day the fee is composed of both a percentage and a flat rate.

Both solutions involve 2 columns, so why not just go with the simple approach, of 2 columns each with the own meaning & data type (even if the same), and no enum column.

@candied_orange I am not "dumping all over the idea". I do not enjoy arguing. I just want to learn what is best practice and do that.

@ErikEidt  My proposed solution uses 3 columns. The enum column is necessary for my idea because in my ideal approach both columns could be non-null. The enum then tells us which columns to use. As Gregory Currie said, the fee could be composed of both % and flat, in the future.

I don't see two separate columns plus an enum.  Either put NULL in one column or use $0 for one and 0% for the other, with a general formula that takes both into account — then no error prone enum.

@PeacefulJames i didn't say you were. We are. But we've only heard one side of this. So ask that question before presenting what we're saying here.

I have seen this situation a few times, a field was "recycled" to a different usage to avoid a datbase migration.  It adds complexity to the application and introduces bugs.  It is not worth the time to save.  Keep the data model simple and straightforward.

This reminds me of a Eastern European national database (20th century) where the same column was used to store the military registration number (for males) and the partner number (for married women). Fun when they accepted women into the army. No, this pattern has been debunked for decades.

Using one field for both values has a benefit that hasn't been mentioned: when there's a critical bug that arises from someone accidentally misusing the field — and there will be one — you'll already know what to look for and will look like a hero when you quickly diagnose and fix the issue.

Your analysis is correct.
Beyond the complexity issue I would add as problems:

The design is misleading and error-prone as it could give the impression of handling in a uniform way the fee field.
It makes it very cumbersome to use typical report generators and query tools on this data, considering the different unit of measures, the different aggregation rules, bit also the different precision/display rules.
Moreover, in an internationalised version, amounts are to be dealt with a currency and a conversion factor whereas this would not be relevant at all for the percentage.

The two-field approach overcomes all these limitations and is hence future proof. The two-field approach is also an implementation of the single table inheritance pattern, which is a proven approach to deal different kind of fees (specialization/inheritance with different attributes) in a single table.
Now in all honesty,  multiplexing the two kind of fields in a single floating point field can work if your app is the only one that accesses it. It'll just require extra care to maintain it and limits the flexibility.

"in an internationalised version, amounts are to be dealt with a currency and a conversion factor whereas this would not be relevant at all for the percentage": but it would be relevant for the presumable other field that contains the amount that is to be multiplied by the percentage.

@phoog this is a relevant remark In view of OP's narrative I understood that the fee is not the actual amount but a kind of fee calculation (formula) limited to the simple cases of fixed amount or percentage. As I was not sure how the fee calculation would be used in the end to calculate the total amount, and in particular, if it would be in the same table, I decided not to address this point.  I nevertheless think that if it would be in the same table table, the amount field would probably be used to sore the calculated fee from separate percentage and nobody would try to save a % field :

Agreed.  Perhaps it's best not to go more deeply into detail than the question does itself, but on the other hand it can be helpful to point the asker to issues that may have been overlooked.  My daily work is awash in issues that were overlooked :-)

floating point for money - no!

@akostadinov I did not  address the point, because OP starts with "I already know that storing money as a float is fatal. I do not want to discuss this.". Otherwise I'd have recommended this article: https://medium.com/the-technical-archaeologist/is-cobol-holding-you-hostage-with-math-5498c0eb428b and I would have proposed the usual exemple of a loop times 100 where I add 0.01 at each iteration, which accumulates an error to a visible state ;-)

There's a much simpler approach here that should bypass any petty database schema design arguments. Your business logic is really this:
TOTAL_COST = (BASE_COST * (1 + PERCENT_FEE)) + FLAT_FEE
Coincidentally in your case, exactly one of PERCENT_FEE and FLAT_FEE is always zero. In this model, we only have one branch of logic instead of two.

Put both PERCENT_FEE and FLAT_FEE columns on your database
Give them both a default value of 0
(Optional) Include a check constraint to ensure exactly one is zero
(Optional) Declare a view with the total cost already computed

Each column means exactly what is says, two numeric columns won't use any more disk space than one numeric and one string, and you're in pretty good shape when your boss asks you how hard it will be to support a formula with both types of fees. The data model already supports it and the calculation logic can be centralized in one place.
For that reason, I wouldn't bother with the constraint on the database table. At most, enforce it in the UI/API before it gets to the database.

Isn't this what the OP already proposed, having the two fields separate?

The approach is correct.  But the argument "if your boss later asks you to..." is a bad one.  You don't design your application for requirements that don't exist yet.

After a while, boss-man comes in and says "well, we have a flat fee for this product, but for these special customers the flat fee is halved".

@FlorianF but sticking to good design practices for the requirements you do have makes your life a lot easier when you have to change the design later.

@FlorianF I mention the support for a future requirement as a bonus. The simplest solution to today's requirements automatically supports a likely future change. Too often we fall into the trap of thinking we have to chose between easy now and easy later. Tunnel vision on exactly today's requirements ironically blinds us from seeing the simplest solution today. That's exactly what's happened here.

This might be overkill for your needs here, but another option that you might not have considered is to separate these values into two separate child tables e.g. PERECENT_FEE and FIXED_FEE which have foreign keys pointing back to the   parent table.
This avoids the need to have null fields and a 'checkboard' table.  As I mentioned above, this may be over-engineered for your needs, but it can be a useful approach when you have heterogeneous data structures.

This is an interesting alternative indeed. It builds on the same idea of considering amount and percentage as two different specialization of fees, but using class table inheritance instead of single table inheritance. However, I'd opt for this more complex scheme, only if more fields would be involved, or if the fee logic would allow combination of several fees.

@Christophe "only if more fields would be involved, or if the fee logic would allow combination of several fees" precisely my stance as well. Having two fields also allows for both a fee and a fixed charge, though. But the first part is really the key. Having 2 fields where you only use one per row isn't a big deal.  But if you have, say, 6 fields per option where only 6 of the 12 (or 18, 24, ...) being used on a given row, it's pretty nasty.  I've actually worked with legacy DBs like this. Just yuck.

@JimmyJames It's one of those areas where there's no right answer -- "checkerboard" tables are a pain to work with, but so are "subclass" tables... I've seen both used in different places, and found both to be regrettable solutions. Given that this one is just two fields (and seems unlikely to expand too much), I'd lean towards checkerboard...

@SimonGeard Agreed. I just added this answer because that nuance might be important to someone other than the OP with this kind of situation.  The sparser a wide table gets, the more this kind of approach is appealing.


more future-proof (if we ever fix the horrible money-as-float problem, these fields will have to be split anyway)

I don't see why this is necessarily the case.
Financial percentages should no more be stored as floats than absolute financial amounts should.
The core use for floats is physical quantities, where exactness is not necessary, where it is desirable that the inexactness be proportional to the overall scale, and where it is more desirable to have a wide range of scale factors  than a monotonic interval between each representable value.
The use for decimal or fixed-point is where exactness is necessary, where precision must be fixed, and where it is more important for every value within a range to have an exact representation than for the range of scale factors to be wide.
So here, both values should be moved over to using a decimal type.

safer (avoids problem of fee being 20000%, for example, which the data could technically allow)

Ease of validation and enforcement of constraints may be a reason. I'd be surprised if there's much in it though.

simpler UI implementation (this is a little bit subjective but I can not imagine a UI where it is not simpler to have the % and the fixed fee in separate fields).

To be honest I can imagine both approaches to the UI. One where there is a drop-down and a single numeric field, another where there are two numeric fields but only one can be filled.
Summary
I don't think there are any decisive reasons one way or the other that always apply.
The choice of how to represent the cases of a union type might be governed by whether there is ever a difference in data type between the cases anywhere in the database, or might be in future, with any difference in data type tending to require separate fields (unless you venture into the realm of "variant" types, or coerce everything to a common denominator like a string representation).
Generally you'd want to be consistent in the approach across the database and across your own practice, if possible, or at least consistent in the default approach which is then only varied for reasons in specific cases.
Another aspect of the choice might be how many cases have to be represented, with more cases of the same data type tending towards sharing fields rather than having an extremely wide table.
Arcane performance criteria might also govern at the extremes. For example, how the desired indexes will work.
My snap judgment is that separate fields would be more flexible in general, but I wouldn't dig in over the issue, especially if someone else is doing the design.

I agree that the percentage should also be stored as a decimal string.

Not a decimal string. A decimal numeric value. I'm not sure how modern databases typically store decimal values, but in ye olden times we would use BCD - 2 digits per byte, plus no need for the decimal point. A 6 digit number with 2 digits after the decimal would take 3 bytes, compared to floating point which would typically take 4 bytes (32 bits, always powers of 2) or string  7 bytes.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the more common approach in my experience (in the last 25 years or more) is to use a twos-complement signed integer (of anywhere between 64 and 128 bits) scaled by a negative power of 10.  For example, the SQL Server MONEY data type is a 64-bit integer with fixed-point scaling by a factor of 10^-4, giving a range from -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807.  In effect, it stores an integer representing a quantity of hundredths of a cent.

You're right, I don't know why I wrote "decimal string". Yesterday was a busy day and my head was fried when I wrote that comment.

I agree with Christophe's answer for the reasons they have stated, however I think its also worth thinking about the alternative (Enum + Value) solution so that we can refute any arguments that support the enum solution, specifically:
Disk Space
Since both solutions have two fields and in both cases you will need to load both fields, there isn't going to be a huge performance difference, technically with a small enum it may be possible to optimize the number of bytes on disk, however bluntly "disk space is cheap" so I don't think you can seriously make that argument to support the enum solution.
Invalid Storage State
A valid argument against the "separate" fields is that the data stored on disk can be in an invalid state, either both fields are set or neither field is set. The enum solution can avoid this with NOT NULL constraints on both fields. This argument can be mitigated (in the separate fields solution) by including a check constraint to prevent a record from being inserted (or updated) with an invalid value - I would suggest that it good practice to enforce data integrity at the database level, in this case and more generally whenever it can be enforced without significant penalty.
ORM
I suspect that the supporter of the enum solution is probably pitching that solution, because the database representation more closely matches their in memory representation (read: they are using an enum in their object model).
This is a bit more tricky to refute, primarily because we have to decide what our argument is, there would appear to be two main choices:

Argue that the in memory representation shouldn't be an enum either.
Argue that we should map the on disk representation to a different one as part of the (de)serialization process.

With only two fee types, the code for either of these options is not going to be particularly complex, however I can see someone making a "what if we need to expand the number of types" argument. In that having an enum means that the logic for calculating the fee is just switch (based on the enum) and serialization is trivial, if the in memory and DB representations are identical.
I would be tempted to shut down this argument by saying "How many fee types can you support with just an enum and a float field?", in that I accept that additional fee types are possible, but it's likely you will need additional fields (such as min quantity for a reduction in fees) to support additional fee types.
Hence the crux of the argument is that having separate fields is the best solution for the problem we currently have and we should consider alternatives if/when we need to implement them (read: we have the full set of requirements).
That last point is a little too hand wavy for my liking, it opens up an argument that the simplest code possible today is a simple enum and direct serialization of that enum into the database.

Given that I am tempted to suggest mapping the separate fields in the DB representation to an enum during the (de)serialization process, based on an argument that it gives us the most flexibility to evolve both the storage and processing models independently as new requirements emerge.

I do not think it is invalid for both fields to be null, or both to be non-null. The table could correspond to a HTML form, where we want to "remember" the value for both, allowing the user to switch their preference without clearing the previous value or doing weird hacky calculations to guess a value.

@PeacefulJames because the solution with one numeric field plus a switch satisfies the business requirements, we know that it is not valid to have non-null values in both fields of a two-field implementation.

Describe how you do the following:

Decide whether you have a percentage or an absolute amount.
Return the absolute amount, no matter what is stored.
(Possibly) Return the percentage, no matter what is stored.
Change what is stored to a percentage, or to an absolute amount.
Make sure that nothing invalid is stored. For example two values.

Now you implement these as functions, and never ever in your life access the fields individually. Decide which data in the database are faster and more space efficient, and that's what you use.
I forgot: If you store a percentage then it must be a percentage of something. For example 20% VAT is a percentage of the cost of an item. If the item costs £99, then 20% and £19.80 are the same amount. However, if the item price changes to £98, then you can leave the percentage unchanged, while the absolute amount changes to £19.60. So you need to make sure that when the item price changes the absolute amount also changes in your database. But if you store the percentage, changing the item price can still change derived values, for example the total amount of VAT on a bill.

The way VAT is normally reported on retail receipts, 20% VAT on an item costing £99 is £16.50, because the sale price includes the VAT.  If you discount the item such that it costs one pound less to the purchaser, the VAT drops to £16.33, meaning your revenue has decreased by 83 pence.  I believe this detail does not change your basic point, however, since the VAT is always proportional, it's just that you have to use rate / (1 + rate) instead of just rate.  If you store percentages you also have to be careful to round first before summing when aggregating.

@phoog: VAT rounding rules are non-trivial. You can't just invent them. Relevant EU court case confirming it's a matter of national law even in the EU.

@MSalters sure, but my point is that regardless of the specific rounding rules you have to apply the rounding separately to each transaction so the rounding "errors" accumulate, because otherwise your sum will be incorrect.  Let's forget VAT and go back to the percentage fee.  If you have three transactions with a base amount of 1.25 and a fee of 5%, that puts each transaction total at 1.31, rounded down from 1.3125.  if you round before summing, you get 3.93; which will reflect the actual revenue.  If you round after summing, you get 3.94, which is incorrect.

@phoog: The linked court case was triggered because the Dutch VAT rules contradict your assumption. The official Dutch order is sum, add VAT, round.

@MSalters the linked court case involves transactions with multiple line items as well as different definitions for the "round" operation (always round down vs. round to nearest, ties up). My point about rounding has, I repeat, nothing to do with VAT per se, but let's return to VAT for another example: Suppose you sell a single €5 item to each of 1000 people under a VAT rate of 20%. You have 1000 receipts that report a VAT-free amount of 4.17 plus VAT of  0.83.  Now regardless of whether the government requires you to pay 833.33 in VAT or 830.00 or 834.00, ...

... you may need to calculate the sum of the amounts reported on the receipts -- either because that's the amount you paid to the tax collector or because you need to account for the difference between that amount and the amount you paid to the tax collector. To sum those amounts, if they must be recalculated at the time of the aggregate query, you must do the rounding per transaction, as it was done at the time of sale, before summing.
